# Dynamic forms to parse CSV in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a Flask app where the main function is taking an uploaded CSV file, turning it into a Pandas dataframe, and then running a series of analyses on it.

The application works, but is somewhat rigid in the upload process requiring it to exactly match the column names and expected values.

I want to provide a fallback function that will dynamically generate forms that will ask the user questions in order to figure out column mappings back to the original template.

So for example if the template that worked was laid out like this:

['Name', 'Phone', 'Email']

and the uploaded version was:

['Customer Name', 'Phone Number', 'Email Address
]

I would want it to ask:

Which of ['Customer Name', 'Phone Number', 'Email Address'] correspond to Name.

Preferably I would like to use Flask-wtf to maintain consistency, unless there is a clearly better way to do this.

I imagine the way to do this would be to do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField

minimum_viable_columns = ['Name', 'Phone', 'Email']

data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)

potential_columns = []
    for x in data.columns.values.tolist():
        if x not in minimum_viable_columns:
            potential_columns.append(x)

missing_columns = []
for x in minimum_viable_columns:
    if x not in claims.columns.values.tolist():
        missing_columns.append(x)


class MatchingForm(FlaskForm):
     field_name = SelectField('Corresponding field name', choices=potential_columns)
```

I would have to generate these forms for each column in missing_columns, and I am trying to figure out a good way to do that and hopefully tie them all to a single submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I ended up landing one involved a loop to create attributes for the form and a loop on the route for flask to capture the values.  The code looks like this:

```
def map_csv():
    possible_columns = session['potential_columns']
    missing_columns = session['missing_columns']

    class MappingForm(FlaskForm):
        submit = SubmitField('Submit new mapping')
        pass

    possible_columns = [(x, x) for x in possible_columns]
    if missing_columns is not None:
        for name in missing_columns:
            setattr(MappingForm, name, SelectField(name, choices=possible_columns))

    form = MappingForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit:
            mapping = {}
            for x in missing_columns:
                column = getattr(form, x)
                mapping[column.data] = x
            session['mapping'] = mapping
            return redirect(url_for('main.upload'))
    return render_template('map_csv.html', form=form)
```